# Can't link back to css when trying to use parent directory

Tags: html, css, amazon-ec2, apache2

I've downloaded apache onto my ec2 amazon VM, and replaced the index.html file. The index.html file is located in www/html. However, when trying to link to my css in www/css via

`<link href="../css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">`,

my css file doesn't seem to get linked. When moving the css file into the same directory and editing the link to say

`<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">`,

it works no problem.Not sure what I'm missing or why it behaves this way.

Comment: Does your HTMl have a <base href=...> from the old domain?

Comment: @covener Nope it doesn't have a base tag.